# Create amplify circular reference with model

Tags: circular-reference, aws-amplify

I am trying to create a circular reference in an amplify graphql schema.

I tried to follow the instructions on [Amplify instructions](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/connection/#has-many).

But when I try to push, I get the following...

An error occurred during the push operation: Schema validation failed.
Directive "connection" may not be used on OBJECT.

```
type Item 
    @model
    @key(name: "byParent", fields: ["id"]) {
    id: ID!
    subItems: [Item] @connection(keyName: "byParent", fields: ["id"])
    name: String
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you do that circular reference? Is it supported?

Comment: Maybe not. but based on the response in https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/issues/1323 is seems like it is.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try like that ?

```
type Item  @model
    @key(name: "byParent", fields: ["parentID"]) {
    id: ID!
    parentID: ID
    subItems: [Item] @connection(keyName: "byParent", fields: ["id"])
    name: String
}
```